# Getting outdated index.d.ts from npmjs

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-install

Hi I have an npm module that I am updating (react-native-fs) but it seems the latest version zip file I got from www.npmjs.org contains an outdated index.d.ts file, causing me failed to use some added new methods in the latest version.

I have checked the source code in the module and it actually contains the latest code, only the index.d.ts is outdated. Thinking I may have some caching issue locally so I did a direct download from www.npmjs.org, confirmed it is the same outdated index.d.ts in the zip file there. Checked the index.d.ts file from the author's site on github, the file there actually is correct (i.e. has the new methods).

Is there any way to resolve this? e.g. notify npmjs to update the zip file? Or locally create an updated index.d.ts file for the module?

In case someone is interested, this is the module that I am having trouble:

> "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-native-fs/-/react-native-fs-2.13.3.tgz",
>
> "_shasum": "a422f0ecd8a093a7e99d8d51ff51440e090a18a8",
>
> "_spec": "react-native-fs@^2.13.3",
>
> "homepage": "https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#readme",

Comment: Actually One time when I faced a similar issue , the source has the changes , but it was not published to npm. Can you check that?

Comment: @KiraAG yes thats what I am describing: the source has it, but not published to npmjs yet. Is there any workaround?